# Find Color of Text Element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

I have a Link component and I want to find out what the color of the text is. How would I do that in React?

I know with Vanilla JS, you can find it with `element.style.color` however if I perform similar with below code using `textEl.style.color` I get `undefined`.

```
export function TextLink({ children, path, inline = false, dash = false }: TextLinkProps) {
  const textEl = useRef("");
  return (
    <StyledLink href={path} inline={inline} dash={dash} ref={textEl}>
      {children}
    </StyledLink>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.getComputedStyle()` and pass the element itself by its `ref` like so:

```js
const ref = React.useRef();
...
...
...

React.useEffect(() => {
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(ref.current)
  console.log(style.color); // rgb(255, 0, 0) 
}, []);
```

[Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Answer (score 0):

Gives `rgb(0, 0, 0)` to me

```
const textEl = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (textEl.current) {
      console.log(window.getComputedStyle(textEl.current).color)
    }
  }, [textEl])
```

Or simply just use `textEl.current.style.color` if you don't need computed one

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting the 'current' with your reference. write it like this :

```
textEl.current.style.color
```